# How do i resolve these depreciation errors in flutter?

Tags: flutter, package, flutter-dependencies, deprecated, deprecation-warning

This [package](https://pub.dev/packages/powerflutter) is used in code, but the package was not updated for last 3 years so need to replace package.

if any one Used this package or replace this [package](https://pub.dev/packages/powerflutter) pls inform me.

error exactly is :-

```
Running "flutter pub get" in project...
Resolving dependencies...
The current Dart SDK version is 2.19.0.

Because build_runner >=2.4.0 requires SDK version >=3.0.0-134.0.dev <4.0.0 and no versions of build_runner match >2.3.3 <2.4.0, build_runner >2.3.3 is forbidden.
And because build_runner 2.3.3 depends on crypto ^3.0.0, build_runner >=2.3.3 requires crypto ^3.0.0.
And because every version of powerflutter depends on uuid ^2.0.0 which depends on crypto ^2.0.0, build_runner >=2.3.3 is incompatible with powerflutter.
So, because tacticboard depends on both powerflutter ^0.1.1+1 and build_runner ^2.3.3, version solving failed.
pub get failed
command: "/Users/Develop/flutter/bin/cache/dart-sdk/bin/dart __deprecated_pub --directory . get --example"
pub env: {
  "FLUTTER_ROOT": "/Users/Develop/flutter",
  "PUB_ENVIRONMENT": "flutter_cli:get",
  "PUB_CACHE": "/Users/mac/.pub-cache",
}
exit code: 1

Process finished with exit code
```

I download the repo of [powerflutter](https://pub.dev/packages/powerflutter) from [here](https://github.com/Powerflutter/powerflutter.git) and tried to customize the repo.

Comment: its look like this package is very outdated

Comment: @rahulVFlutterAndroid Yes I know do you know any other replacement of this package?

Comment: For purpose of? dependency injection?

Comment: Yes, it's for dependency injection

Comment: You can use getit package

Comment: I know this is tricky, but.... depreciation = financial term for losing value of an asset over time.  deprecation is a soon-to-be-obsolete (and removed) feature which should be removed from old code and not used in new code.

Comment: @RandalSchwartz  yes package is very outdated. Can you please suggest me any replacement for this.

Answer (score 4):

I've downgraded `build_runner` to `^2.3.3` because version `2.4.0` relies on the 3.0.0 sdk which is in alpha.

You can either change the `environment` `sdk` property in pubspec.yaml to target the sdk version that is needed by your packages (although I wouldn't do so since sdk 3.0.0 is in alpha), either downgrade the dependencies that requires such sdk version.

So, summarized:

- Downgrade to `^2.3.3` since it does **not** rely on sdk versions greater than 3.0.0
- Run `flutter pub get`

Answer (score 0):

you need to add git in your project,

then run the command line :"flutter upgrade"

Building flutter tool...
Flutter is already up to date on channel stable
Flutter 3.7.3 • channel stable • https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
Framework • revision 9944297138 (7 days ago) • 2023-02-08 15:46:04 -0800
Engine • revision 248290d6d5
Tools • Dart 2.19.2 • DevTools 2.20.1

Answer (score 0):

Running following command in terminal fixed the issue for me:
sudo chown -R $(whoami) <path to your local flutter/bin/cache/pkg directory>

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).